# How did/What made Elizabeth go into a coma for 10 months?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-blacklist

In Season 5 Episode 8 of The Blacklist, Liz went into a coma for 10 months.

I fail to see how a knock to the head could have achieved that. Did I miss something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I fail to see how a knock to the head could have achieved that.

Actually a coma (at least a temporary one) is quite common for [**Traumatic Brain Injuries**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traumatic_brain_injury).

> In the first few weeks after a brain injury, swelling, bleeding or changes in brain chemistry often affect the function of healthy brain tissue. The injured person's eyes may remain closed, and the person may not show signs of awareness.
>
> Some terms that might be used in these early stages of recovery are:
>
> - Coma: The person is unconscious, does not respond to visual stimulation or sounds, and is unable to communicate or show emotional responses.
> - Vegetative State: The person has sleep-wake cycles, and startles or briefly orients to visual stimulation and sounds.
> - Minimally Conscious State: The person is partially conscious, knows where sounds and visual stimulation are coming from, reaches for objects, responds to commands now and then, can vocalize at times, and shows emotion.
>
> [**Source**](http://www.msktc.org/tbi/factsheets/Understanding-TBI/The-Recovery-Process-For-Traumatic-Brain-Injury)

Granted 10 months is a *long* time to be in a coma but obviously this was aplot-driven *time-jump*.

So, no it's not unusual for TBIs to be caused by head injuries and these often lead to comas.